# File upload using Put Http method

Tags: php, http, file-upload, put

I want to upload a files to a remote server. For this I have read that we could use put method to upload the file.

The user will be provided a form where they can upload one or 2 files. 
This file should be uploaded to the other server.

The code I have used for file upload using http put is as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init($api_url);
$data = array(
  'filename' => 'filename.html',   
  );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
// Make the REST call, returning the result
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (!$response) {
    die("Connection Failure.n");
}
```

The put request is sent but the file does not get uploaded as required. The file name goes as data. Also the filename.html file is in the root location of the webserver. How do I upload a file?

Comment: Aren't you missing `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);`?

Comment: If i add this line then data array in the response goes blank also the file does not get uploaded. Although the put request is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that you didn't send contents of the file.
2. Accepting your request as a upload is completely up to the server. Ask the server's administrator how to upload a file or read the API document for the server if is provided.

Comment: Yes.. I had not the file contents in the code before.. I am now sending the file content using file_get_contents($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name']); and am also performing a base64_encode() on the content..

Comment: @user3230561 `file_get_contents($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name']);` is for reading contents from a file uploaded by a client, not for sending a file. And `$_FILES` is ["An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). So I think it does not work for PUT method.

Comment: I am fetching the contents and then posting the data using the $data array variable. Also I removed the http_build_query function and I perform a json encode on the $data variable. Using this method I am able to send the file content to the api

Comment: @user3230561 According to [php.net](http://kr1.php.net/curl_setopt), "To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path". Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP you can use the code below:

```
#Initiate cURL object
$curl = curl_init();
#Set your URL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://local.simbiat.ru');
#Indicate, that you plan to upload a file
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
#Indicate your protocol
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
#Set flags for transfer
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
#Disable header (optional)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
#Set HTTP method to PUT
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
#Indicate the file you want to upload
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, fopen('path_to_file', 'rb'));
#Indicate the size of the file (it does not look like this is mandatory, though)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize('path_to_file'));
#Only use below option on TEST environment if you have a self-signed certificate!!! On production this can cause security issues
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
#Execute
curl_exec($curl);
```